# C# Settings error with visual studio

Tags: c#, settings, application-settings

When  I try to build application I get 3 errors dealing with the settings.  I've done the settings the same as I always do, but this time I'm getting errors and don't know why.

Here's the settings file code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="SAM.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="AllowGlass" Type="DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">True</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="ApplicationSkinName" Roaming="true" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

And here is the errors I get:

```
Error   1   Too many characters in character literal    1   15  SAM
Error   2   Too many characters in character literal    1   30  SAM
Error   3   A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   1   1   SAM
```

Again I have absolutely no idea why I'm getting these errors.  So any help no matter how small will be greatly appreciated by me.

Answer (score 1):

Is build action of file is set to `Compile`?  If yes, try again after setting it to `None`.